# Stack Overflow prevents me from posting an answer claiming markdown text using HTML tags, is unformatted code

Tags: markdown

Markdown formatting normally relies on indentations. However, I was having copy-pasting issues with the markdown text between Stack Overflow and Google Docs. I had to do it because Stack Overflow drafts auto-save was not reliable. So I decided to copy the HTML code of the rendered markdown from Stack Overflow instead. Because HTML is (ideally) completely supported in markdown and does not rely on indentations at all.

This went well until I was ready to post the answer on Stack Overflow and then I got an error saying unformatted code. Unfortunately, I didn't take a screenshot at the time but here's the same error text I found on other people's posts:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I now posted that answer by manually rewriting it as markdown. And I can't attempt to replicate it now because it would be bad if I post the same answer again in the name of testing.

Here is my markdown:

```
<h3>My hypotheses:</h3>
<p>We know that Dart creates different constructors for creating const and non-const objects (even constructors marked as const internally have a non-const copy). The compiler could’ve been made to create a const constructor on its own when it encounters a const object creation, but this leads to redundancy (both time and memory wise) because of issues pertaining code segment memory allocation to the class and pre-compiled header files. So it is better for the class itself to mark the constructor as a const constructor, and hence the rule 1.</p>
<p>Restrictions on modifying attributes, is handled in the form of removing their setter methods. Methods are common for the class, and can not be separated between const and non-const objects without creating different versions of the class. Although, this is likely possible for the compiler to implement internally, Dart perhaps chose the simple approach of leveraging existing mechanisms, which results in rule 2. Because a final attribute does not have a setter method, whether the class has a const constructor or not.</p>
<p>For rule 3,
There are two reasons why we might want to have a body for a constructor:</p>
<ol>
<li>Calculating the values of the attributes from the parameters before setting them. But to assign the calculated values to the attribute of the object being created, the setter function has to exist. But it doesn’t for final attributes. So this use case can not be applied.</li>
<li>Creating side effects: But since the const object is created at compile time, what side effects are we expecting that we can’t hardcode ourselves? Besides, it restricts the compiler on the sequence of passes it makes and the way it compiles codes. And coders may also have wrong expectations of the flow of execution of the various const object creations with respect to each other and the rest of the code. So this use case is not to be applied either.</li>
</ol>
<p>When neither of the use cases is applied (and both cases require additional work to implement, as normally in languages the constructor body is executed after creating the object), why even allow a body? If at all, we need something to be run from the object, we can do it at runtime with class methods (not the constructor)</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way, perhaps via another tag, to tell Stack Overflow explicitly that this is markdown text and not unformatted HTML code?